# Why do i get this error i dont know why? sketch.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at sketch.js:18

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, p5.js

I got this error from my console.

> sketch.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
> at sketch.js:18

And i dont know why?

Here is my Html Code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="js/p5.js"></script>
  <script src="js/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/p5.sound.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@2/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

  <script src="sketch.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylegenerator.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <button>Random</button>
    <h1>Result</h1>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my javascript code.

```
    var txt;

let btnRandom = document.querySelector('button');
let result = document.querySelector('h1')

function preload() {
    txt = loadStrings("license.txt");
}

function getRandomNumber(min, max){
    let step1 = max - min +1;
    let step2 = Math.random() * step1;
    let result = Math.floor(step2) + min;

    return result;
}

btnRandom.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let index = getRandomNumber(0, txt.length-1);
    result.innerText = txt[index];
})

function setup(){
    noCanvas();
}
```

please help me. I dont know how to fix this error.

I am using visual studio code and p5.js.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access an element that is initiated after the Javascript. You can fix this by loading the js file after the HTML element you want to select:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="js/p5.js"></script>
  <script src="js/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/p5.sound.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@2/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylegenerator.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <button>Random</button>
    <h1>Result</h1>
</div>

<script src="sketch.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```